# After submit the form how do I redirect to welcome component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After submit the form in login.js, I would like to redirect to Welcome.js. I am new to React.

Login.js

```
class Login extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            email : "",
            password : ""
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(e){
        this.setState({
            ...this.state, [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        alert("wow")
        this.setState({
            email : '',
            password : ''
        })
    }


    render(){
        console.log(this.state)
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                <input 
                placeholder = "email"
                type = "text"
                name = "email"
                value = {this.state.email}
                onChange = {this.handleChange}
                />

                <input 
                placeholder = "password"
                type = "password"
                name = "password"
                value = {this.state.password}
                onChange = {this.handleChange}
                />

                <button 
                type="submit"
                >Log in</button>

            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Welcome.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Welcome = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>Welome</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Welcome;
```

Comment: you have to use router for doing this

Comment: Do you use routing?...

Comment: can you give me any source material  for routing n react ?  @JibinFrancis

Comment: can you give me any source material for routing n react ? @DennisVash

Comment: Yes, try google, its a good source

Comment: below is the source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You may also conditionally display different component depending on state.**

Below, I added a new "submitted" state, and set it to true when submitted. And I conditionally return different component base on the "submitted" state;

```
if (this.state.submitted) return <Welcome />
```

your modified code

```
class Login extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            email : "",
            password : "",
            submitted: false
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(e){
        this.setState({
            ...this.state, [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        alert("wow")
        this.setState({
            email : '',
            password : '',
            submitted: true
        })
    }


    render(){
        console.log(this.state)
        if (this.state.submitted) return <Welcome />

        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                <input 
                placeholder = "email"
                type = "text"
                name = "email"
                value = {this.state.email}
                onChange = {this.handleChange}
                />

                <input 
                placeholder = "password"
                type = "password"
                name = "password"
                value = {this.state.password}
                onChange = {this.handleChange}
                />

                <button 
                type="submit"
                >Log in</button>

            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is where `React Router` comes in, you can programmatically navigate in your app

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

Then use it to navigate after anything. An example:

```
    import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

    let history = useHistory(); 
    
    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        alert("wow");
        history.push("/welcome")
        this.setState({
            email : '',
            password : ''
        });

    }
```

Comment: If you navigate away and the component unmounts is it necessary to clear out the state? Should likely also note that the `useHistory` hook will only work within a `Router` context.

Comment: Not really... i just made an edit to the post to give an answer. You don't need to do that.